# Which Persistent Context is better to in terms of performance in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

As we know there are two Persistent contexts in hibernate
namely **org.hibernate.Session** and **javax.persistent.EntityManager**
but some of the methods which are there in Session not there in EntityManager
for example
**session.delete(entity);** is there in Session
but there is no delete in EntityManager
for that we have to use
**entityManager.remove(entity);** so which Context to use for persisting entity in database and which is faster between two.

As of my knowing differance is
entity instance passed to the org.hibernate.Session delete method can be either in managed or detached state, while the entity instance passed to remove on javax.persistence.EntityManager must be in managed state.

Comment: Good question. I don't know about performance, but all I can say is if you want to be 100% in JPA standards, then you have to use the EntityManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance difference; Hibernate just exposes its services through the JPA's `EntityManager`, in addition to the native `Session`. If you don't care for JPA compatibility (I don't see any good reason why you should), use the native `Session` to leverage the full feature set of Hibernate.

Comment: -->ya you are wright ,and i went through the documentation and find that JPA API's has delegation to the Hibernate API's
for example
entityManager.remove(entity); has a delegation call to delete method of session

Answer (score 0):

Very Good Question
Many Persistent API's have delegation to org.hibernate API's
so i think better is to use org.hibernate API's directly